# How do I make this image responsive and not small on IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

Link to my website: http://foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/about.php

Picture of problem:

http://tinypic.com/r/11t20k7/5

I am having a lot of difficulty getting my image to be responsive and not shrink on IE 8. The page itself works fine on most other browsers. I want the page to look like it does on most modern browsers.

All of my code is located in external style sheets (after right clicking view source):

```
<div id ="about_center">
                <div id="dp_section">
                    <img src="images/Business%20Picture.jpg" id="dp" alt="Leonard Pfautsch"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "new_line_about">
                <div id='about_section'>
                    <p>
                    My name is Leonard Pfautsch.
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    Currently I am an student at Marist College in Poughkeepsie, NY. My area of study is Information Technology, but I am still
                    very interested in the Computer Science field as well. At school and at home, I am always studying and learning new things.  
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    In my studies, I have really gained a fascination for all aspects of technology. This includes:
                    web development, internetworking, system administration, information security, data management, computer architecture, 
                    cloud computing, gaming, and mobile application development.
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    In all aspects of work, I always strive for perfection. Whenever I work, I make sure the job is done correctly and efficiently.
                    I always do my best with any challenge I am faced with. In terms of client satisfaction, I will go above and beyond to give
                    people the best experience possible. 
                </p>
                </div>
                </div>
        </section>      


/* ABOUT */
#dp_section {
    float:left;
}
#dp {
    border:10px solid #161616;
    width:200px;
    max-width:100%;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #272727; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
}
#about_section {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}

section{
width:100%;
}


#about_center{
width:200px;
height:auto;
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;
}
```

I tried everything in my knowledge to fix this but I am stuck. I also tried responsive.min.js which did fix most of my issues, but not this one. If anybody could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add the code to the question?  "view source" is not a valid way to share your code.

Comment: Sure I can do that if it makes it easier. Just give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to clear your Browser Cache? The picture works fine for me all the way back to IE 7, but your text in IE 7 is rendering below the image. `#dp` in your CSS should probably have a height, and `float:left;` like:

```
#dp{
  background-color: black;
  border: 10px solid #161616;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #272727;
  margin: 0 10px 10px -10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 279px;
  float: left;
}
```

Note:

Your Picture is 1509px wide by 2104px high. You should use an image editor to resize your image and store it on your site at the appropriate width and height, otherwize it takes longer to load. You can surround it like:

```
<a id='dpLink' href='images/Business%20Picture.jpg'>
  <img alt='Leonard Pfautsch' id='dp' src='yourResizedImage.jpg' />
</a>
```

If you do want to make a link to your full size image make sure your CSS looks more like:

```
#dpLink,#dp{
  width: 200px;
  height: 279px;
  float: left;
}
#dpLink{
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 10px 10px -10px;
}
#dp{
  background-color: black;
  border: 10px solid #161616;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #272727;
}
```

Additionally, `border-radius` and `box-shadow` are HTML5, so they won't render in Browsers before IE 9.

Comment: Yes I actually want to fix the text below on IE 7 as well and make that the same as the modern browsers. If you could help me with that too I would be forever in your debt. I did know beforehand about the large image, but I will try to fix that to see if that was the problem. Give me some time I will add another comment to see if your solution works or if it does not work. I use this for testing too: http://netrenderer.com/index.php

Comment: I was able to fix the IE 7 issue where text was on the next line. I am still getting the squeezed picture on IE 8 after testing it with the link I included in my previous comment. It gives me the full sized picture if I completely get rid of width:200px; max-width:100%; I tried what you said and it still is not working. Do you have any other suggestions?